# Trying to check the number of lines in a text file as a variable for a for-loop in Unix

Tags: variables, unix, numbers, lines

so far:

```
find . -name 'prob*' > problems.txt
NUMOFFILES=$(wc -l problems.txt)
for((j = 1; j < NUMOFFILES; j++))
do

*insert imaginary commands here*

done
```

However, I keep on getting messages saying that it's an invalid arithmetic operation. My guess is that the answer I got from NUMOFFILES is in the form of a string. My question is how do I set the number of lines in a text file as a variable for a for-loop.

Thanks!

-edit1: I'm also fairly new to Unix and this is for an assignment. Therefore, I ask that the solutions that any kind soul gives me have that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you're not using backticks?

```
NUMOFFILES=`wc -l < problems.txt`
```

I think the method you're using might be a Bash-4-only construct, and I get myself trying to use those all the time on the machines at work that are 3.x. I think that it's leaving NUMOFFILES unassigned, and you can't do a comparison against it because of that.

The for loop looks suspect too. If this isn't a shell script, please say so.

Comment: Oh no! It didn't work!
"./prob2: line 17: ((: j <= 1 problems.txt: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt")"

It's a shell script, by the way.

Comment: @user2896865 I fixed it. wc was returning a string containing more than just the number. Using the input redirection fixes that. The easy way to debug these is to run each command at the command line by itself to get the syntax right.